# What is the name of the device that allows switching between two power sources?

Tags: electrical, terminology

What is the component called that allows switching between two power sources so that only one of them can be used at a time?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [transfer switch](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_switch) allows you to switch between two or more power sources.

An [Interlock](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_interlock_kit) is a device that prevents a breaker or switch from being toggled. In the situation of two power sources, an interlock is used to allow only one power source to be on at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is totally safe for the two supplies to be connected together, to avoid risks of a faulty switch it is usual to use a 'change-over panel', containing two contactors, where either one being closed opens a switch to prevent the other closing electrically (electrical interlocking), and often a lever or system of levers between the two also peventing both being closed at the same time (mechanical interlocking)

Comment: So an interlock or transfer switch, just like the previous answer given almost TWO YEARS AGO.